# PictureBox increases in size with the same inputs when calling FitToScreen()

Tags: c#, .net, layout, picturebox

I’m having an issue with some functionality in my program. It is supposed to fit an image to the screen, which it does, but subsequent calls to this function cause the image to increase in size ever so slightly. It becomes apparent after issuing the command about five times. Here’s an example gif of the bug:

[image: fit to screen bug]

The source for this program is hosted [here](https://github.com/akappel/CinemaStrips/tree/issue1). Make sure you are in the "issue1" branch, as it is specifically geared toward this issue. It is self-contained; download, compile, run. It also includes a test "comic" to use.

The `FitToScreen()` functionality is stored in *MainWindow.cs*:

```
private void FitToScreen()
{
    //TODO: frameHeight (aka Height of picture box's tablelayout cell) keeps growing with subsequent calls...
    // ensure a comic has been loaded
    if (!_comicController.ComicLoaded())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No comic loaded!", "CinemaStrips");
        return;
    }

    // make the window's height as tall as screen
    var screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
    Height = screenHeight;
    var frameHeight = tableLayoutPanel1.GetRowHeights()[1];

    // send the comicController the size it needs to try and fit into
    Width = _comicController.FitComicViewToWindow(frameHeight);

    // put window location at 0 height and center width of screen
    Top = 0;
    var screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
    Left = (screenWidth - Width)/2;
}
```

The call to `Width = _comicController.FitComicViewToWindow(frameHeight)` is stored in *ComicController.cs* and allows the comic to be displayed with the correct aspect ratio, based on the height given, and returns a width for the window to use:

```
public int FitComicViewToWindow(int frameHeight)
{
    //Take into account in margins around the ComicView
    var marginedHeight = frameHeight - ComicView.Margin.Vertical;
    //Return the image's width if its height is smaller than the windowHeight
    if (marginedHeight >= _comic.CurrentPage.Height /* <-- Law of Demeter?*/) return _comic.CurrentPage.Width;

    //Calculate the aspect ratio
    var aspectedWidth = marginedHeight * _comic.CurrentPage.Width / _comic.CurrentPage.Height;

    //Make sure that the actual page fills the inside of the picturebox when it resizes
    ComicView.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    ComicView.Size = new Size(aspectedWidth, marginedHeight);

    //return the aspected width so the window can resize
    return aspectedWidth;
}
```

And that's how it works! **Some things to note:**
The picturebox that displays the comic is added to a TableLayoutPanel during initialization. The TLP row's height that stores the picturebox is what is used for calculations, even though it is of itself not modified. **Stepping through the debugger shows that this row's height increases by 1 pixel every function call.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated and please let me know what you think!

Comment: Any Margins, Paddings or Borders set? Have you tried a Math.Round for calculating the aspect ratio?

Comment: @TaW in the `_comicController.FitComicViewToWindow(frameHeight)` call, I take into account the picturebox's vertical margins with `var marginedHeight = frameHeight - ComicView.Margin.Vertical`. Maybe it has something to do with not taking into consideration the Horizontal margins as well?

Comment: Sorry man, I posted my answer to the wrong question!

Comment: Hm, doesn't sound likely; the width stays the same? What happens when you use an image that is landscape?

Comment: Does the height grow by 1 for every image?

Comment: @TaW It's all good! The width increases as the height increases. Edit: Also, I have not tried any images in landscape.

Comment: @chaddienhart Yes, the height grows by 1 for every call to FitToScreen(), for whatever image is loaded.

Comment: _It's all good! The width increases as the height increases._ Meaning what? That you are happy or that you're unhappy in both directions?

Comment: @TaW I'm unhappy with both directions. The function call should remain consistent each time, fitting to screen. But it steadily increases by a pixel after each call, in both directions.

Comment: What is the type of `_comic.CurrentPage.Width` and `_comic.CurrentPage.Height`? If they are int then you are truncating the value of the division and multiplication in `var aspectedWidth = marginedHeight * _comic.CurrentPage.Width / _comic.CurrentPage.Height;` Try casting one to a float like `var aspectedWidth = marginedHeight * _comic.CurrentPage.Width / (float)_comic.CurrentPage.Height;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simpler than I realized; when getting the `frameHeight`, one must remember to remove an additional 1 pixel. This gives the "inner" height of the table layout panel's row containing our picturebox. For my implementation, I removed this pixel before passing the frameHeight into the `Width = _comicController.FitComicViewToWindow(frameHeight)` call.

The FitToScreen() now produces predictable results.